# Selecting base resistor on op-amp controlled constant current LED driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, led-driver, constant-current

How do I calculate the appropriate value for R1 and R8 so I don't get extra current flowing through my transistor bases at low voltage?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDVY9P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I inherited this project mid-design and don't have any experience with op-amps. Normally, V2 is higher but the design as presented is the required low-voltage spec. With this low voltage supply circuit, the collector potentials drop lower than the bases, causing excess current (~10mA) to flow out of the op-amp and into the bases. Using simulation I've figured out that if I beef up R1 and R8 to the 2.5k-5k range I can reduce this current to a reasonable level (<2mA), but I'd like to know how to design it correctly from the start.

Comment: *the collectors are at a lower potential than the bases* Then Q1 and Q2 are in saturation and you should really aim for them to be in active mode so that their Vc > Vb (collector voltage > base voltage). Start by removing R4 because I don't see how it does anything but waste power. If removing R4 is not enough then V2 needs to have a higher voltage and/or you need to remove an LED. When Q1 (and Q2) operate in saturation their base current would be Ic / beta which is small enough for the opamp to drive.

Comment: Also I do not understand why Q2, R8 and R7 are there. I would just make R3 7 ohms and I would get the same current. Also the presence of R2 doesn't make much sense to me unless you want to compensate for the opamp's input current but then I would want to see a resistor of around 20 kohm, not 1 k. The voltage at the + input of the opamp is only 192 mV which is low, not every opamp can handle that so check.

Comment: *I'd like to know how to design it correctly from the start.* Then start by listing what the behavior of the circuit should be (not what it is but what it should be). It looks like a constant current driver to me but a somewhat overcomplicated one.

Comment: BTW, there's a fantastically easier way to do this, if you don't need it to be "perfect".    https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/transistor/active-constant-current-source.php

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry for the confusion. The intention is indeed for Vc > Vb, which is why I pointed out the low collector voltage, albeit unclearly. The current sense resistance is split between R4 and R3 because that's where the previous engineer decided to take the feedback voltage from. V2 is normally expected to be higher, but the circuit needs to still function at this low-voltage condition per customer spec. Q2 etc. is for heat dissipation and was included for completeness' sake.

Comment: Question edited to clarify voltage condition.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I calculate 140mA total emitter current.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You're right, miscalculation form my side

Answer (score 3):

You can set a lower limit on the resistor value from the maximum current you want to flow from the op-amp.

You can set an upper limit on the resistor value from the minimum current required to turn the transistor on. That requires finding the minimum op-amp voltage under load when railed and so on, so a bit of calculation and datasheet interpretation.

It's possible that the upper limit is lower than the lower limit based on your preferences in the first instance, and you'll just have to live with the current limiting in the op-amp, adjust your preferences, or add some external UVLO (undervoltage lock-out) circuitry if that concerns you.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer, but there's not enough space in the 'comments' to describe this...

A key behaviour of op-amps, when configured such as you have above  (with the output connected to the "-" terminal) is that they'll try to drive their output to whatever they have to to MAKE THE INPUT TERMINALS THE SAME VOLTAGE.   THis is classic "negative feedback"

Further, for simplicity, consider the opamp inputs to be OPEN CIRCUITS (i.e. no current flows into them)

Your "+" terminal is easy.  It's a voltage divider.  So there's 5.5*(24/(24+101) = 1.056 volts.  That's a fixed value, no matter what else happens here.

The "-" terminal is a little more involved

Since NO CURRENT flows into the "-" input, that means there is no current flowing through the 1k resistor (R2), which further means whatever voltage is present at the top of the 14 ohm resistor will (should) be same voltage at the "-" pin.  i.e. 1.056V

So you have by ohms law (E=IR)   1.056 = I * 14.....  I= 75mA

The opamp will drive its output up or down to whatever value it has to such that the above is true.  This is the essence of negative feedback.

The only thing that can make it NOT work is if the voltage the opamp has to reach is beyond what it can reach... THis would be dictated by the opamps voltage supply.  If it's +- 12V, you can get the output to maybe +-11V or thereabouts (Opamp dependent).

Now note the 100 ohm base resistor hasn't been mentioned yet.  This is because it's exact value really doesn't matter.  Again, the opamp will do what it has to to get 1.056V on that resistor.

If you find you can't get 1.056 and it's TOO LOW, that means the transistor can't be driven hard enough, and maybe lowering that 100 ohms is necessary.  If it's always too high, the 100 ohms may need to be raised.

I'm not at leisure right now to do all the math, but I'm hoping this description of how this all works turns a light bulb on for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The op amp will try to keep the top of R3 at 1V.  That means ~140mA total emitter current (Q1 and Q2).

When things are working properly, the required base current depends on the transistors' current gain.  On the low-gain side, I_emitter/I_base might be around 20.  To be safe say 15 unless the data sheet for the transistor says differently.

At a gain of 15 or so, the op amp will need to supply 9mA.  Assuming a conservative 1V drop across B-E, and that your op amp output can go all the way to 5.5V (which I assume is its supply), that means 3.5V / R1 = 0.0045.

R1 comes out to 777 ohms.  You should be able to increase R1 and R8 to 750 ohms or so without impairing the operation of the circuit.  Your op amp will then provide at most 12mA of current, whether the LEDs are sufficiently powered or not.

Check the data sheet for Q1 and Q2, though.  If it promises you more gain, then you can raise R1 and R8 more.  Also, you might want to run another resistor like R2 to the top of R7.  That way your output current will be what you want even if Q1 and Q2 aren't perfectly matched.